# RegEx in SAP 7.5 start with and end after first occurrence of character

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, netweaver

I am working on SAP NetWeaver 7.5 and having the following string

```
/InstrId/**BTXXXXXXXXX**/ /EndToEndId/REF 2102231XX4/ /BICFI/XXXXXRAAXXX/
```

I need to get as a result `BTXXXXXXXXX` which should also be not more than 16 characters.

I have tried `^/InstrId/(.*)/$`

But I get BTXXXXXXXXX/ /EndToEndId/REF 2102231XX4/ /BICFI/XXXXXRA AXXX.

Obviously * is greedy, so I tried `^/InstrId/(.*?)/$`, but I get an error that the expression is not valid.

Comment: SAP (NetWeaver) 7.5 is ambiguous, SAP is a software company and there are many software. Which RegEx implementation are you talking about, or if you don't know in which programming language are you using it? If you are talking about some ABAP 7.5x versions, there are several RegEx implementations (POSIX, PCRE).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `.*` to a negated character class `[^/]*` not crossing matching `/`

If you have to match the whole line, then you can use `.*` and end the pattern with a forward slash at the end.

```
^/InstrId/([^/]{1,16}).*/$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^/` Match `/` at the start of the string
- `InstrId/` Match literally
- `([^/]{1,16})` Capture group 1, match 1-16 chars other than `/`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `/$` Match `/` at the end of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u5lpEh/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I get what is between / and / , but I do not get the first 16 characters. Example: in this case /InstrId/20230222130245970/ I need to get 2023022213024597 instead I get 20230222130245970.

Comment: @Chrysanthi I see what you mean, I have updated the answer using a quantifier `{1,16}`

Answer (score 0):

`$` requires that the match is anchored to the end of the line.

You probably want simply

```
^/InstrId/([^/]*)
```

which matches as may *non-slash* characters as possible.

If you want to limit the length, you can match exactly 16 non-slash characters:

```
^/InstrId/([^/]{16})
```

If the string could sometimes be shorter than 16 characters, try

```
^/InstrId/([^/]{1,16})
```

which matches as many as possible, up to a maximum of 16.

If you want to require exactly 16 digits, possibly prefixed with non-digit, non-slash characters,

```
^/InstrId/([^/0-9]*[0-9]{16})
```

Perhaps review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which covers some common beginner questions and has links to more learning resources.